# "sudo cordova build android" error with CordovaLib:compileDebugJava on mac os x

Tags: android, macos, cordova, build

I'm trying to build an android app with Cordova. I'm using Cordova 5.2.0 and I want to build for android 4.3.1, so in my project.properties I've inserted:

```
target=android-18
```

Unfortunately when i launch

```
sudo cordova build android
```

I obtain error in the "CordovaLib:compileDebugJava" task.

This is the complete error report:

```
    Mac-di-Luca:studioapp4 XXXXXXX$ sudo cordova build android
Running command: /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/XXXXXXX/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientCertRequest
location: package android.webkit
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientCertRequest
location: class org.apache.cordova.CordovaClientCertRequest
    private final ClientCertRequest request;
                  ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientCertRequest
location: class org.apache.cordova.CordovaClientCertRequest
    public CordovaClientCertRequest(ClientCertRequest request) {
                                    ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PermissionRequest
location: package android.webkit
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
                     ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:253: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class FileChooserParams
location: class android.webkit.WebChromeClient
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                                                                                                                         ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:273: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PermissionRequest
location: class org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                                          ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientCertRequest
location: package android.webkit
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java:116: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientCertRequest
location: class org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient
    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
                                                           ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:251: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable LOLLIPOP
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:271: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable LOLLIPOP
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java:240: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable KITKAT
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                                  ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java:123: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable KITKAT
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                                                            ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java:327: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
location: class android.view.View
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
                      ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable LOLLIPOP
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(android.webkit.WebView,boolean)
location: class android.webkit.CookieManager
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
                         ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java:59: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable LOLLIPOP
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java:60: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method flush()
location: class android.webkit.CookieManager
            cookieManager.flush();
                         ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:259: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable FileChooserParams
location: class android.webkit.WebChromeClient
                    Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
                                                  ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:252: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:272: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java:192: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable KITKAT
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                                                                              ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java:243: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)
location: class android.webkit.WebView
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                   ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java:114: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java:352: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable KITKAT
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && "content".equals(uri.getScheme());
                                                                                 ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
24 errors
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.856 secs

/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/studioapp4/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to run cordova? Anyway, it seems a classpath related problem.

Comment: Thanks, what do you think I need to do to resolve classpath problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because you're set a too lower Android target for this version of Cordova.

E.g. The class android.webkit.ClientCertRequest was added only in [API level 21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ClientCertRequest.html)

If you look at the [latest Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#install-sdk-packages), you could see that *Android 5.1.1 (API 22) platform SDK* is required.

To compile, you must install, and set as target, a more newer android platform SDK.

Comment: Thanks, so i can't use api level 18?

Comment: I'm installing api LEVEL 22 and next i will try again to build.